# How do I get a field label by the field name?

Tags: 7, entities

How do I get a field label by the field name in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The label is set per instance (not per field) so you would use the [`field_info_instance()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7) function with some appropriate arguments:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$bundle_name = 'article';
$field_name = 'field_some_field';

$info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);

$label = $info['label'];
```

There's a bunch of other useful functions in the [Field Info API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/group/field_info/7) documentation that might be helpful in case you haven't seen it already.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that

Comment: That works for english.  Doesn't seem to work when trying to get the translated version of a title.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to **print the field label** of a node is:

```
<?php print $content['field_your_field_name']['#title']; ?>
```

(I've discovered it after a lot of *print_r* arrays and objects of Drupal! If it's so easy, why isn't explained anywhere, or why is so hidden that I've not found the trick? And passed a long time from the question to this answer...)