# Field Info API as REST

Tags: entities, 8

We would like to get label for the field.

As per previous question: [How do I get a field label by the field name?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38115/how-do-i-get-a-field-label-by-the-field-name)

But I need to get this through the REST API of Drupal.

Could anyone please suggest what should be the approach to use the Field API from as REST service.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to create a custom resource as described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/783460).

In the call back put the piece of code answered [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38115/how-do-i-get-a-field-label-by-the-field-name)

taking args int he resource, But I suggest using [field_info_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) as it only takes the field name and returns all details as an array that you could choose what you need to return