# How can I get the taxonomy title from its machine name? (drupal 7)

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am trying to get the taxonomy name which I already got its machine name.
The content type "manage field" looks like following image:
[image]

Right now, I already got the value "field_application_type." How can I get the lable "application type"(in the red circle) for this machine name(in the blue circle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to obtain a Label of a taxonomy vocabulary would be something like this:

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('machine_name');
echo check_plain($vocabulary->name);
```

However, looking at your screenshot, I guess you actually want to have the field Label of the taxonomy reference field.

In that case your question is a duplicate of [How do I get a field label by the field name?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38115/how-do-i-get-a-field-label-by-the-field-name)

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right, my question is duplicate. The answer there works well.